# How to access Docker Toolbox containers from locahost?

Tags: docker, localhost, port, portforwarding, docker-toolbox

I'm currently using docker toolbox for windows and am having trouble accessing the container instances from localhost.

[Picture of the Port details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvnwc.png)

All the ports are up and running, but I can't seem to access them from localhost through my browser. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the container on the host network `--net=host`.

Right now your container should be available from `0.0.0.0`.

> By default, Docker exposes container ports to the IP address 0.0.0.0
>   (this matches any IP on the system). If you prefer, you can tell
>   Docker which IP to bind on.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 <image>
```